# val().replace in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way prevent adding a newline if the current line is empty in a textarea? example:

Allowed:

```
The brown
candle
```

Prevent:

```
The brown
          // --> empty line break 
candle
          // --> empty line break 
          // --> empty line break
```

Basically I want to avoid empty line breaks. How can I do this?

This is what I tried but no success.

```
$('textarea#comment').val( $('textarea#comment').val().replace(/\s*$/,"") );
```

Comment: You already asked that, don't you ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Yes, I had it removed within 2minutes. Posted as a fresh one after few more tries.

Comment: You need to detect the enter key is pressed or not. If it is the enter key then backtrack from it.     


`$(document).keypress(function(e) {    
    if(e.which == 13) {    
        alert('You pressed enter!');    
    }    
});`

Comment: @Konok thanks. but that doesn't prevent line breaks if the text is pasted.

Comment: Would be easier to process the text on the server side, are you specifically looking for a JS solution?

Comment: @leuquim yes. but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: @Becky I'm just asking because if you're gonna use JS, there's nobody stopping somone from sending some text with line breaks using AJAX.

So, if it's something important you'll need to verify it on the server side, if it's not important keep looking for a JS solution.

Comment: Manipulating the textarea value "on input", basically always ends with bad user-experience (cursor jumping and worse). I strongly suggest handling such things *after* the user has finished doing her/his thing.

Answer (score 3):

The following will prevent empty lines, while keeping the cursor at a *somewhat* sane position. Though you need to check `selectionEnd` and `input-event` support for your project.

```js
$('.no-extra-lines').on('input', function () {
  var notAllowed = /(\r?\n){2,}/g, c = this.selectionEnd, len = this.value.length;

  if (notAllowed.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(notAllowed, '$1');
    this.selectionEnd = c + this.value.length - len;
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea class="no-extra-lines" rows="12" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%">The brown
candle</textarea>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should  check and replace current value of text-area on key up to achieve this as following :

```js
$('textarea#comment').on('keyup', function() {
    $('textarea#comment').val($('textarea#comment').val().replace(/^(\r\n)|(\n\n)/,''));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="comment"></textarea>
```

Comment: This stops what the OP said was acceptable (line break on a line with text!)

Comment: but multiple spaces are still allowed. well +1 for blocked enter.

Comment: Try pressing ENTER and hold it down. Yeah.

Comment: Thanks but that's same as mine? Dosen't allow any linebreaks?